# node.js - EJS - Server-Sent Events (SSE) Error: EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream"

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, server-side

I am working on a Node.js application using Express, EJS, and Server-Sent Events (SSE). The SSE route is set up to handle real-time updates on the client side. However, I'm encountering an error that says:

`EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.`

1. routes/processContent.js (SSE Route):

```
// routes/processContent.js


// SSE route
router.get("/processContent", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
  res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  res.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

  const sendEvent = (data) => {
    res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`);
  };

  // Call the processContentAll function with SSE support
  processContentAll(openai, Keyword, sendEvent)
    .then(() => {
      // Signal the end of events
      res.end();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    });
});

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("processContent");
});

module.exports = router;

});
```

2.views/processContent.ejs (Client-Side EJS Template):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Processed Keywords</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Processed Keywords</h1>
    <ul id="keywordList"></ul>

    <script>
      const eventSource = new EventSource("/processContent");
      eventSource.onmessage = function (event) {
        const keyword = JSON.parse(event.data);
        const listItem = document.createElement("li");
        listItem.textContent = `Keyword: ${keyword.keywords}, Title: ${keyword.title}, Subtitle: ${keyword.subTitle}`;
        document.getElementById("keywordList").appendChild(listItem);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Additional Information:**

The server responds with a "Content-Type" of "text/html" instead of "text/event-stream" for the SSE route.
The issue is observed when using EJS templates along with SSE.

**Steps Taken:**

Checked and confirmed the correct setup of "Content-Type" headers in the SSE route.
Verified that the EJS template does not include content that might interfere with SSE responses.

**Expected Result:**
The SSE route should respond with a "Content-Type" of "text/event-stream," but it is currently responding with "text/html," leading to the mentioned error.

**Request for Assistance:**
I am seeking guidance on resolving this issue and ensuring that the SSE route responds with the correct "Content-Type" for successful Server-Sent Events.